# Where to get a brace like this?

Tags: tabletop, table-making, materials

I took two from an old table I bought retail. Need two more though. No idea where to get something like this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVcL4.jpg

Comment: This doesn't seem on topic for this site. Those are just braces, available almost anywhere if you search online. Or you can use cross-bracing made of of tensioned steel wire. But shopping questions are, generally, off-topic for Woodworking SE.

Comment: Unlikely you will find one the exact length you need.  Have one made by a fabrication shop or make one yourself, 1/2" Copper pipe, hammer down the ends, drill holes, paint black.

Comment: There are lots of Ikea style knock-off braces out there that are adjustable in size -- just two lengths that can be connected with two self-tapping screws along their lengths.

Comment: @jdv Where can I find something like this? My google results are always for these L-looking braces. I just want a rod that I can screw into a table

Comment: @Shane what you want to search on is either "crossbrace" or "turnbuckles".

Comment: Just as a side comment, the need for braces like this shows the poor nature of tubular legs like these (or the brackets that attach them to the underside of the tabletop).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping question